# Git: How to make a single commit of multiple commits when merging pull request?

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket, gitlab

At work, we always generate 2 commits when merging a PR. The first one would be a commit for a feature and a separate commit for the merge.

Personally, I find having merge commits would clutter the git log. So I wonder what's the convention or best practices for this?

Comment: git checkout master && git pull && git checkout mybranch && git rebase master && git checkout master && git merge mybranch will do a merge without any additional branch basically because your are rebasing mybranch on top of the master branch.

Comment: What do you mean generated first commit (commit for a feature)? When you merge a PR, it only generate a merged commit (as you said the second generated commit-separate commit for the merge)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [squash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---squash) while merging pull request, it will create a single commit. Switch to branch in which you have to merge (let's assume it's master), merge it using squash, commit and push, as follows:

```
git checkout master
git merge pull-request-branch --squash
git commit -m "Pull request merged in master"
git push origin master
```

Comment: On Bitbucket Cloud this is an option in the "merge" dialog.

Comment: Is this better than having merge commits though?